# Why does Django not save a form inserted to a formset with jQuery?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a formset, containing forms to modify infos about uploaded files. When i upload a new file i insert a new form into the formset, change the formset form count and update the page with jQuery to contain the new form.

To be a bit more specific: In the basic view, that i request with a 'GET' i return a formset. Later on i upload a file with an jQuery 'POST', and on success return a rendered formset form that i then insert into the existing formset with jQuery. This is the view that responds to the ajax request:

```
def upload_view(request):

  form=NewItemForm(request.POST,request.FILES)

  if form.is_valid():
    # set the current user as the items creator
    item=form.instance
    item.creator=request.user
    # save the form to create the database entry
    form.save()

    # until this point everything works as expected, and is saved to the database
    # now i render a template with the existing data to create the form to be
    # inserted into the formset
    t = loader.get_template('formsetform.html')
    # create a formset containing only the just uploaded item
    formset = ChangeItemFormset(prefix='itemforms', queryset=Item.objects.filter(pk__in=[item.id]))
    # create a placeholder prefix for the form inside the formset
    # this prefix is then being replaced with jQuery to be the correct prefix
    prefix = '__prefix__'
    formset.forms[0].prefix = 'itemforms-%s'%prefix
    form=formset.forms[0]

    # push the form inside the formset to the context
    context = RequestContext(request)
    context.update({'form':form})

    #render the template and return it to the client
    itemdiv = t.render(context)
    json = simpleJson.dumps({'itemdiv':itemdiv})
    return HttpResponse(response)
```

When i submit the formset after inserting such a new form, it is sent to a view function that processes it. The formset validates. What then happens is a miracle to me, which is why i ask this question.

```
ipdb> form.cleaned_data
{'id': <Item: funktech.aif>, 'is_checked': True, 'bpm': None, 'name': u'changed_name.aif', 'tags': u''}
ipdb> Item.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['id'].id)
<Item: funktech.aif>
ipdb> form.save()
<Item: changed_name.aif>
ipdb> Item.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['id'].id)
<Item: funktech.aif>
ipdb> Item.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['id'].id).name
u'funktech.aif'
```

The uploaded item does exist in the database, but the information about it is not updated with form.save()

After refreshing the page once things work as expected:

```
ipdb> form.cleaned_data
{'id': <Item: funktech.aif>, 'is_checked': True, 'bpm': None, 'name': u'changed_name.aif', 'tags': u''}
ipdb> Item.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['id'].id)
<Item: funktech.aif>
ipdb> form.save()
<Item: changed_name.aif>
ipdb> Item.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['id'].id)
<Item: changed_name.aif>
ipdb> Item.objects.get(pk=form.cleaned_data['id'].id).name
u'changed_name.aif'
```

If the Item wouldn't exist in the database i would assume i messed something in the uploader, but the database entry is there.

**edit:**
Only difference i could find so far is this: when i just uploaded such an item and did not reresh th page this happens:

```
ipdb> form.changed_data
['name', 'id', 'is_checked']
```

After refreshing the page this is different:

```
ipdb> form.changed_data
['name', 'is_checked']
```

**edit2:**
Ok, so this is what the code in my view looks like:

```
the_formset = ChangeItemFormset(request.POST, prefix='itemforms')

for form in the_formset.forms:
    form.save()
```

And the forms.py:

```
#a form to upload an item
class NewItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewItemForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('file','name','bpm','tags')

# create a formset to contain ChangeItemForms
ChangeItemFormsetBase=modelformset_factory(Item,extra=0,form=ChangeItemForm)
class ChangeItemFormset(ChangeItemFormsetBase):
    #add a checkbox to decide wether a Item should be changed or not.
    def add_fields(self,form,index):
        super(ChangeItemFormset, self).add_fields(form,index)
        form.fields['is_checked'] = forms.BooleanField(required=False)
```

Hope this helps...

**edit3:**
One more thing i found out in the  meantime (besides a workaround ;) ) is this: The instance of the form is not linked to the correct object (or, at least, not to the one i think it should be):

```
ipdb> item_form=form.instance
ipdb> item_form
<Item: funktech.aif>
ipdb> item_cleaned=form.cleaned_data['id']
ipdb> item_cleaned
<Item: funktech.aif>
ipdb> item_cleaned==item_form
False
ipdb> item_db=Item.objects.get(pk=item_cleaned.id)
ipdb> item_db==item_cleaned
True
```

Looks like Django has interpreted the form as being connected to a new instance of Item, which is not the same as the one i created in the upload_view. But then why does the cleaned_data contain the correct item-instance, the one that is stored to the the database during the update_view?

Although i did a workaround, i still do not understand how Django handles form data in this case, so if anybody could explain that behaviour i would very much appreciate that.

Comment: Please post the necessary code to reproduce (i'm wondering why you have such a cleaned data "'id': <Loop: funktech.aif>" that's not common)

Comment: That is a result of using the formset, afaik. I did not override the form clean functions, if that is what you are asking for.

Comment: You mentioned you created a workaround to this problem.  I have a very similar problem, but you do not provide the workaround you used.  I would find it most helpful.  It seems to me that the extra forms are not rendered correctly after their corresponding model instance is saved.  Maybe that is by design?